# How to remove the gap between header and cell of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` and it has a header and a cell.
I want to remove the gap between the header and the cell..
How to do that in `swift`?

Here is my view...

[image]

I added background colour to the `collectionView` and header and cell also..

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: you can try to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`

Comment: I tried..it's not working @Cheng-YuHsu

Comment: could you please add background color to header and cell view and post the snapshot, also snap shot of your collection view's size inspector settings,that will help us to understand the issue better.

Comment: Yes, I added background color... please see the changes. @RDC

Comment: what you use autoresizing or sizeclasses?

Comment: sizeclasses @MiteshDobareeya

Comment: if the green is cell and light gray one is your content then you must have issue with auto-layout settings

Comment: Then check your sizeclasses you set it proper related to size or not.

Comment: No, the green is for collectionView and for cell the color is different it is not visible here

Comment: If still any problem then disable your size classes and check it by using autoresizing.

Answer (score 6):

Use the property **section Inset** of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
// Here you can set according your requirement
```

[image]

For more reference: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-view-using-swift/

Answer (score 1):

use the property `sectionInset` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1;
```

in Swift:

```
var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
```

Comment: i think the OP would like to have Swift syntax, could you please translate the syntax to Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Attaching screenshot of storyboard screen. Set as per that your storyboard and check. Hope your problem will be solved.

[image]

Comment: I did the changes.. Still the gap is there.. Min spacing was by default 10..I changed it to 0.. But the gap is huge.

Comment: Check its is not set anywhere programatically.

Comment: No its not set programatically anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I Forgot to set section Inset to zero.
It solved my problem.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
}
```

On UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
 let k_cViewPadding = 8.0

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let cellDiffference:CGFloat = CGFloat(k_cViewPadding*4)
            return(CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width-cellDiffference)/3, (collectionView.frame.size.width-cellDiffference)/3))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code you have to set `UIEdgeInsets` for spacing.

```
private let collectionViewLayout: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.register(TopExpertCustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TopExpertCollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#F1F1F1")
    return collectionView
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom your UIEdgeInsetsMake:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  //{top, left, bottom, right};
}
```